# Sending javaMail attachement of any type from database

Tags: grails, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I'm have domain class with property that represents files uploaded on my GSP. I've defined that file as byte array (byte [] file). When some specific action happens I'm sending mail with attachments from. This is part of my SendMail service:

```
int i = 1;
        [requestInstance.picture1, requestInstance.picture2, requestInstance.picture3].each(){
            if(it.length != 0){
                DataSource image = new ByteArrayDataSource(it, "image/jpeg");
                helper.addAttachment("image" + i + ".jpg", image);  
                i++;
            }
         }
```

This works fine with image files. But now I want to be able to work with all file types and I'm wondering how to implement this. Also, I want to save real file name in database. All help is welcomed.

Comment: Do you know file names of other files? or just binary data?

Comment: @splix Those are all binary data wich is defined in domain class. But that doesn't matter. It can be changed - domain class, GSP and controller logic. I just want to do it the best way.

Comment: At this case i can't understand your problem. You just attaching a binary data, with a filename/mimetype (same sort of things). I mean, this code works for any binary data, isnt it?

Comment: @splix See my comment to Bill Shannon comment. I hope that clarifies my problem. If not, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see where the file name and MIME type are specified in your code.  It should be straightforward to save and restore that information from your database along with the attachment data.

If you're trying to figure out from the byte array of data what the MIME type is and what a good filename would be, that's a harder problem.  Try [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html).

Comment: So I guess the proper way to do this is to have aditional field in the table where I will hold mimetypes? But it's still a bit limited. What I really want is to be able to send any type of file with correct extension. I need to persist those files in database because they are linked with my domain class instances and I need to know what instance they are connected to.

Comment: You can get mimetype from filename extension. Don you know filename?